# How Can i implement Intent Into Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Here am got listview into the tab fragment. now i want to start new activity according to the list item. How can i implement intent activity for the following code.

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {


public TabFragment1(){}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_fragment1, container, false);

    String[] menuItems = {"list1","list2","list3"};
    ListView listView =(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.activity_list_item,
            menuItems
    );
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: You mean implement intent on item selected ?

Comment: yes brother. please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set setOnItemClickListener to your listview and call intent according to your list position :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                if(position == 0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

               else if(position == 1){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

               //Do as above for rest of the list items
            }
        });
```

To solve your problem, use this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.activity_list_item,
            R.id.Your_textView_id_in_activity_list_item
            menuItems
    );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: when i implemented like this it is showing an error;





 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: Where are you implementing the above code? It should be placed after listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter); in onCreateView

Comment: ya, i placed it there. bt still its showing the same error

Comment: This error is occuring because you are using LinearLayout or something else as parent instead of TextView in activity_list_item.xml . Check my updated answer.

Comment: R.layout.activity_list_item,
R.id.Your_textView_id_in_activity_list_item

its worked for me.  thank you so much brother. thanks a lot.

Comment: It's my pleasure. :)